# Unity3D Facebook Scores API

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I am learning how to use the Facebook Scores API for a Facebook Canvas game made in Unity.
I have read Facebook's online documentation and require code examples of how to query and sort friends scores from the Scores API.
Can you recommend a link to such code examples?

My specific goal:
The game's score screen will display 3 scores, retrieved from Facebook's Score API:

1. my friends high score who has the next highest score compared to my score.
2. my high score.
3. my friends high score who has the next lowest score compared to my score.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The facebook API will help you build a leaderboard: 
[Scores API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores/)

The Facebook Unity Game Tutorial will help setup your project. Please don't forget to test it outside the Editor:
[enter link description here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/unity/unity-tutorial)

I have also found very useful the sample that comes with the Facebook SDK for Unity. Sadly this is my first post and I can't give you more than two links.

Since the Facebook API call will return the list of the logged user's friends that have also authorized the game in descending order, you will need to manually iterate through to grab what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you user3578268,
Thanks for spending the time to reply to my question.
Yes, I have read Facebook's Scores API documentation and experimented with their provided example Unity projects.
You said: "you will need to manually iterate through to grab what you are looking for"
This is exactly the type of code example I am looking for.
My goal is to learn how to get the scores, sort through the scores, and pull out 3 specific scores based on my criteria stated above.

Comment: This example may help you get started [link](http://frozenfishy.blogspot.com/2014/02/technical-post-1-integrating-facebook_2476.html)

Comment: a bit late but check this link, I think it's what you were looking for at that point http://greyzoned.com/tutorials/facebook-sdk-in-unity-scores-api/